# "connect-pnponline -PnPO365ManagementShell -launchbrowser"is raising this Error:- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, administration, pnp-powershell, pnp

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint online communication site which have MFA enabled, I tried running this command:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>  connect-pnponline "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/"  -PnPO365ManagementShell -launchbrowser
```

where i will get a popup >> then i will enter the code >> enter username and password >> close the popup >> but I got this error:

```
WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code D****9
to authenticate.
WARNING: Code has been copied to clipboard
connect-pnponline : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:2
```

Although I entered the above code and enter the username and password and confirm the MFA.

Anyone advice please?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -UseWebLogin
```

**OR**

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -PnPManagementShell -LaunchBrowser
```

> **-UseWebLogin**
>
> If you want to connect to SharePoint with browser based login. This is required when you have **multi-factor authentication (MFA) enabled**.

**Source**: [Connect-PnPOnline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline)

Comment: there is no command named "-PnPManagementShell"

Comment: There is..it is given in documentation link (in my answer). However, to login with MFA enabled I have used `-UseWebLogin` before and it works. try using it and let me know if it works.

Comment: you mean `-PnPO365ManagementShell` not `-PnPManagementShell`

Comment: if i use `-UseWebLogin` i will be login automatically,, but if i try to perform any action will get access denied ...

Comment: I mean `-PnPManagementShell` (See Example 12 given in above link). Also `PnPO365ManagementShell` is Alias of `-PnPManagementShell`.

Comment: ok i already tried `connect-pnponline "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/***/"  -PnPO365ManagementShell -launchbrowser` and it raise the error mentioned on my question

Comment: While using `-UseWebLogin` you are getting logged in maybe because the credentials are saved somewhere (default browser or credentials manager).

Comment: now inside the default browser i am already login using the correct username and password (the office 365 admin)

Answer (score 0):

As @Ganesh Sanap suggested, you may need to `-UseWebLogin` to sign in the MFA enabled account. And there is a new parameter `-ForceAuthentication` in the latest version of PnP PowerShell:

- https://twitter.com/PnpPowershell/status/1335362866069856258
- https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/connecting.html

If this parameter is specified it will clear the cookies and you can log in with different credentials. This should prevent from auto-login.